# Kendo UI Grid dataSource schema model fields - add custom attributes to fields

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource, kendo-validator

I want to add custom attributes to model fields.Think can I add `data-email-msg` as attribute to a field in `Kendo Grid`.(Please look at my example and how I add it..)

here is a example.....

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    title: "Name",
    attributes: {
      "class": "table-cell",
      style: "text-align: right; font-size: 14px",
      data-email-msg : "enter a valid email massage"
    }
  } ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" }, { name: "John Doe" }]
});
```

I already know that above is wrong. I am asking, is there a way to do that ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `data-email-msg` in quotes like `"data-email-msg"`

Comment: I just saw `class` in quotes and decided to try `data-email-msg` in quotes too ;)

Comment: After seeing your answer it hit on me ...
Thanks bro